# C# How to check Remote IP Address from the Local Network

Tags: c#, ip-address

Currently, I'm working on a Windows Based System which uses mySQL as Database. The database can be on a Remote Computer connected to the same Network.
My Problem is, how can I check if this Remote Address to be my Database source is existing or currently reachable.

Comment: Connect to it. It is isn't reachable, it doesn't connect, make sure you handle the error gracefully. (Seriously though, I do not think it is the responsibility of the database-driven application to do network related stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool CheckConnectionStatus()
{
    String strConnection="/*your connection string here*/";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
       try
      {        
       con.Open();
       con.Close();
      }
       catch(Exception e)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else
   {
    return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: This would leak connections when you check it when already open.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: yes ofcourse, but can we have any other option betterthan this? i'm thinking of...

Comment: close it before returning. Or use the `IsConnected` flag that might be available.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: i used `State` peroperty to check wether it is opened or not, can you please have a look?

Comment: This still leaks because you don't close the connection and its object will be garbage collected.

Comment: is it required to open the connection?

Comment: @NicOlGadingan: yes , we need to Open the Connection and see wether it throws excepttion or not, if it does nt throw any exception then connection with remote machine is successfull.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks for your help.
I'm a beginner so i have a lot to learn.

Comment: @NicOlGadingan: You are Welcome :) All the best.